# How to send a variable from one class to another

Tags: c#, .net, forms, class

Here is the code as it now stands, I will include all of the code of the program as I left some bits out before. The bits I have changed due to your help I have emphasized with asterisks and ///
The first class is the standard one created from Windows Forms when directly editing your form.

```
namespace DistanceEstimatorFinal
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool saved;

        public Form1()
        {

            dataPoints mydataPoints = new dataPoints();
            InitializeComponent();
            dataPoint a = mydataPoints.getItem(0);
            latTextBox.Text = a.CurLatitude;
            longTextbox.Text = a.CurLongtitude;
            eleTextBox.Text = a.CurElevation;
            saved = true;

        }             

        private void latTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void openDataListToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|Text files ( *.txt)|*.txt |All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog(this).Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {
                *var dp = new dataPoints (ofd.FileName);* /////

            }
        }       



        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (saved)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Save?", "Data Not Saved", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo).Equals(DialogResult.Yes))
                {
                    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                    sfd.ShowDialog();

                }

            }
        }

        private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|Text files ( *.txt)|*.txt |All files (*.*)|*.*";
            sfd1.ShowDialog();
        }

    }
}
```

This class was designed to read in the data from a file, I am currently adapting it to read in a file from the open function.

```
namespace DistanceEstimatorFinal
{    
    public class dataPoints
    {              
        List<dataPoint> Points;
        string p;

        public dataPoints(string path)
        {
            p = path;
            Points = new List<dataPoint>();

            StreamReader tr = new StreamReader(p);

            string input;
            while ((input = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] bits = input.Split(',');
                dataPoint a = new dataPoint(bits[0],bits[1],bits[2]);              
                Points.Add(a);  


            }

            tr.Close();
        }





        internal dataPoint getItem(int p)
        {
            if (p < Points.Count)
            {
                return Points[p];
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

This file held the three variables Distance, latitude and Longtitude.

```
namespace DistanceEstimatorFinal
{
    class dataPoint
    {
        private string latitude;
        private string longtitude;
        private string elevation;

        public dataPoint()                               //Overloaded incase no value available
        {
            latitude = "No Latitude Specified";
            longtitude = "No Longtitude Specified";
            elevation = "No Elevation Specified";

        }

        public dataPoint(string Latitude, string Longtitude, string Elevation)
        {

            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.latitude = Latitude;
            this.longtitude = Longtitude;
            this.elevation = Elevation;

        }

        public string CurLongtitude { get { return this.longtitude; } }
        public string CurLatitude { get { return this.latitude; } }
        public string CurElevation { get { return this.elevation; } }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried making it part of the constructor?

Comment: By that do you mean including it in the public form1() constructor at the top? Yes I have, but I don't know how to do that, if I put pathFile; at the top it just gets underlined in red.

Comment: Are you creating dataPoints only from Form1's code? If so, you should consider Konstantin's answer.

Comment: Why downvoting this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pathFile` is a method local variable, so it's inacccesible anywhere except the body of that method (here `openDataListToolStripMenuItem_Click`).

You could add a parameter to your `dataPoints` constructor to pass that value to the class:

```
public class dataPoints
{
    List<dataPoint> Points;
    public dataPoints(string path)
    {
        Points = new List<dataPoint>();
        //here `path` from constructor arguments
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path); 
        //...rest part of your code
    }
```

Besides you'll have to pass the value to this constructor. You didn't show the code, you have to create `dataPoints` instanses.

```
var dp = new dataPoints(pathFile);
```

But remember, `pathFile` is accessible only in `openDataListToolStripMenuItem_Click`. So you should either create the `dataPoints` right there, or make your `pathFile` a field of a form for it to be accessible in any method of that form. Then you'd get an opportunity to access `pathFile` in any method of this form.

---

According to [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574442/trying-to-send-a-file-to-another-class-in-c-sharp), this should look like:

```
private void openDataListToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|Text files ( *.txt)|*.txt |All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (ofd.ShowDialog(this).Equals(DialogResult.OK))
    {            
        //actually you don't even need to have a separate `pathFile` variable
        //just pass the value from the dialog straight to your `dataPoints` object
        var dp = new dataPoints(ofd.FileName);
        //...rest of your code
    }
}
```

P.S.: off-topic, but, please, consider reading [MSDN Guidelines for Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thankyou for all your help. I'm just trying to understand.

Comment: @user1744093 you're welcome to ask here, if something is not clear

Comment: Ok i passed the value from the dialog to the datapoints object by creating a consutructor p, however, now when i put the constructor p into the streamreader it returns with an error saying "Value cannot be null"

Comment: I have edited it and included the rest of the code. Your more than welcome to stop if you like I am aware my coding needs much work :S

Comment: @user1744093 you've added another constructor, while you only needed to add a parameter to the existing one. Reread my answer attentively

Comment: Do you mean to add the parameter var dp to the existing dataPoints COnstructor? Like thie public dataPoints ( var dp) ?

Comment: @user1744093 actually, I've written, what I mean, in my answer at once...you only need to see the first code snippet in it. Nevertheless I've edited your question, having written the same there. So, check your question, `dataPoints` class code

Comment: Got it working, some of the code under the constructor in form1 was stopping it working. Some sleep helped a great deal. Thankyou for your patience and persistance :-)